Adding login with microsoft to keycloak
I've been implementing keycloak as my authorization server, and most of it works as expected, however i'm a bit stumbed by the Microsoft identity provider.
I may be misunderstanding a core cencept about adding "login with MS" and "Login with Google", and all the other added social logins.
When i add MS as an identity provider, i do it be creating an enterprise application in azure, and filling ind client Id and client Secret, and leaving the tenant Id blank, to allow multitenant.
However, i'm still bound to users in that specifik tenant, which sort of makes sense, as the Identity provider is bound to an application in my tenant.
But that doesn't let me achieve my goal of letting users, who exist in my system, login with their MS login, which is out of my control.
Eg. when i login with google to my stackoverflow account, i don't install anything before hand.
This way i would have to add an Identity provider for each differenct customer, for their respective MS tenant, which is not feasible.
How would i go about supporting something like here on Stackoverflow, where the users could login with MS, and that MS login/oid/identifier would be mapped to an existing user in my system ?
If it's not supported out of the box, would it then mean creating my own authentication flow, or maybe extending keycloak with a custom provider ?

Sounds like the main thing you need is to determine the user's authentication method at runtime. I will explain how such an approach works but it would require work in Keycloak that may not be trivial.
In Keycloak you will need to configure separate  OIDC authentication methods for each customer organization. Also ensure that each user has a tenant ID in their account data.
For each user, you must identify attributes about them (like their tenant ID or preferred authentication methods) before you trigger authentication.
For example, use the type of approach that systems like Office 365 use:

Run an action that prompts the user for an identifier like their email

Run an action that looks up the user's account and its attributes and calculates the user's authentication methods

Run an action that presents the user with a personalized list of their authentication methods (if there are multiple)

Or run an action to route the user directly to their single authentication method.


To implement such flows you make customizations in the authorization server. For Keycloak you would need to look into the building blocks from the Authentication SPA I believe.
